# Select the most Profitable Month and Year for each product in SQL

Tags: sql, procedure

I need to create a procedure in SQL which will display the best year and month  for each product based on the productID column.
I've tried several select statements, but I did not manage to count and display the max.

What is the correct select statement to use to return this information?

The table I'm querying is:

[image: Sample]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include examples and a summary of the queries that you have already tried.

Comment: Here you go: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer